# Control's ClientID changes after Page_PreRender

Tags: asp.net, debugging

Something really strange is happening.  I have a control that inherits `asp:DataGrid` with `ID="dgLookups"`.  I added `<%: dgLookups.ClienID %>` immediately following the DataGrid in the .ascx that uses it and the datagrid's ClientID is still `ctl08_ctl06_dgLookup` during the Render phase of the page life cycle.

This is where it gets weird.  I'm finding two different behaviors.  Whichever the behavior is, it happens sometime between this point during Render and the time it shows up in the DOM.

1. The generated table element's ID is changed to `ctl08_ctl06_dgLookup_ctl00`.
2. The generated table element *gains an additional* ID attribute of `ctl08_ctl06_dgLookup_ctl00`, added to the beginning of the element.

In both cases, this breaks scripts that rely on the element id being <s>`ctl08_ctl06_dgLookup`</s> the same as the control's ClientID.

I had thought it might be a client-side script, even despite the ID having a very ASP.net-esque suffix, but I checked the raw response in Chrome's Network tab of the Developer Tools, and the ID has already been added.  Interestingly, the response has both IDs, but the DOM only has the one.

I also thought it might be some bizarre circumstance due to the DataGrid being inside an `asp:UpdatePanel`, but commenting out the UpdatePanel did not fix the issue.

Setting the DataGrid's `ClientIDMode="Static"` does fix the issue, but this is not ideal, especially since this issue is showing up in multiple controls; all of them began bugging out at the same time, so presumably all are by the same root issue.

I don't even know how to continue debugging this.  Any thoughts?

#### UPDATE 1

I added

```
<% Control dgLookup = this.FindControlRecursive("dgLookup");
   if (dgLookup != null)
   {
       Response.Write(dgLookup.ClientID);
   }
%>
```

to the end of `Default.aspx`, and the output is `ctl08_ctl06_dgLookup`.

#### UPDATE 2

In the javascript console, I ran:

```
$("[id*='ctl00']")
```

The results are the table and all the items in a specific column of the table.  It's as if something is manually adding the suffix.

#### UPDATE 3

I noticed that `dgLookup.EffectiveClientIDMode` was set to `AutoID`.  When I manually set `ClientIDMode` to `Predictable`, the EffectiveClientIDMode changed, but the added id attribute did not.

Comment: Scripts must not rely on IDs generated by the server-side.

Comment: They rely on `<%: dgLookup.ClintID %>`, plus the `ClientIDMode` is set to `Predictable`.  Further, these scripts are generated by a framework DLL I have no control over.

Comment: @king.code That is not correct. Setting the ClientIDMode to Static will allow you to use the same ID's on the client and server side.